# TypeScript can't match return value of Array.map() callback with its generic parameter

Tags: typescript

I have the following code ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCWATAXFAdgVwFsAjCAJygF8BtAXSgB9k0soBnYU1HAc0toCh%20oSFADiAHgAqUCAA9gEHOlawAfAijS5CpSpQZsXAGZkoASXR86AfnOXsOCADcyAbkFywAe1LAoAYy8cdhl5UgBDf2ALDSlQnWU1AApw0giQbEkASmwJSVVaBHVU9IA6AnCwcTzVVSSk-UsKLKLmLPcgA)):

```js
type A = { id: number }[] | { id: string }[]

type G<T extends A> = T extends { id: infer Id }[] ? Id : never;

export const extractId = <T extends A>(array: T): G<T>[] => array.map<G<T>>(({ id }) => id);
```

I can't figure why I get the error

```
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'G<T>'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'G<T>'.(2322)
```

Not sure whether this is a bug on the side of the compiler or an issue with my code. Interestingly enough, `array.map<G<A>>(({ id }) => id)` compiles just fine.

Comment: The compiler *defers* evaluating conditional types that depend on as-yet-unspecified generic type parameters, like `G<T>` inside the body of `extractId`.  If you want better behavior, you can switch to indexed access types like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbdLbw).  Does that meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, please [edit] your example to show a failing use case.

Comment: @jcalz, thanks for your reply! Your solution is valid and technically works, but I'm interested in the approach involving `infer` and conditional types specifically, because using indexed types here is the first thing that comes to mind. I'd love to learn more about why my approach doesn't work. Where can I read about *deferring* of CT evaluation?

Comment: I'm happy to write up an answer explaining the situation and pointing to sources for deferring conditional types that depend on unresolved generics, if that's what you're looking for

Comment: @jcalz, that’d be extremely helpful! I’m curious about the source of the problem and believe that sorting this out will improve my understanding of TS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler isn't really able to do a lot of higher order reasoning around the behavior of *unspecified* [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.

When you have a generic class like `class Foo<T> {/*...*/}` or a generic function like `function foo<T>(/*...*/){/*...*/}`, users of class instances and callers of the function must *specify* the generic type parameter like `T`, as in `const f: Foo<string> = /*...*/` or `foo<string>(/*...*/)`, where `T` has been specified as `string` in both cases.  Often users/callers don't need to do this explicitly; the compiler can often infer these types from context and specify them that way, but they must be specified.  You can think of these *specific types* as "type constants" that are completely nailed down and known to the compiler.  The compiler is fairly good at dealing with specific types; the results of manipulating values of specific types tend to be accurate.

But inside the body of generic classes and generic functions, these type parameters are *unspecified*.  They act like "type variables" that can represent ranges of possible types. These type parameters may be [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), but that's not the same as specifying them; `T extends string` just means that whatever `T` is specified with it will have to be assignable to `string`, but `T` can still be all sorts of things assignable to `string`, like `"foo" | "bar"`, for example.  Anyway, the compiler cannot know what type an unspecified type parameter will end up being, and is not very good about higher order reasoning where the implications of manipulating values of unspecified types can be followed accurately.

There are a few type operations that the compiler can represent accurately, but often the compiler will either *defer* evaluation of the resulting type, or *prematurely* evaluate the type.

---

Sometimes the compiler *defers* evaluation of the resulting type, treating it as an opaque type which only resolves to something else upon specification.  This is often *type safe* but not particularly *usable* because it won't be able to verify that any value of a differently represented type is assignable to it.  A [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on an unspecified type parameter is a good example of this.  Your `G<T>` type is like this:

```
function foo<T extends A>(id: T[number]["id"]) {
    let gt: G<T>;
    gt = id; // error!
}
```

The compiler cannot see that `T[number]["id"]` is assignable to `G<T>`, even though it must be.  It doesn't know *what* `G<T>` will turn out to be, and it doesn't really try.

I think [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) is probably the canonical issue for how deferring conditional types that depend on unspecified type parameters leads to unpleasantness.  That issue is about function return types in particular, but it's the same general problem.

---

Sometimes the compiler *prematurely evaluates* the resulting type, by specifying the generic type parameter with its constraint, even though this isn't always correct.  It's easy to use, but also easy to misuse. For example:

```
function foo<T extends A>(t: T) {
    const elem = t[0];
    /* const elem: { id: number; } | { id: string; }

    t[1] = elem; // okay?
}
```

Here, the type of `t` has been prematurely specified from `T` to `A` when you access its `0` index, so `elem` is of type `{id: number} | {id: string}` instead of type `T[0]`.  This is not necessarily wrong, but it is artificially wide, and therefore bad things can happen in lines like `t[1] = elem`.  If `T` happens to be specified later with the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) `[{id: number}, {id: string}]`, that line would be in error, since you'd be assigning a `number` to a `string`.

In your case, the `array.map()` causes `array` to be widened to `A` prematurely, at which point the elements are seen as the widened type `{id: number} | {id: string}`, so its `id` property is `number | string`.

Sometimes these two behaviors interact poorly together, also.  In your case, `number | string`, arrived at by premature widening, is not seen as assignable to `G<T>`, which cannot be inspected further due to deferred evaluation.

You can look at [microsoft/TypeScript#33181](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181) for an example of where this sort of thing happens and a description of the widening behavior.

---

There are only a few situations where the compiler can keep track of operations on generic type parameters, and they are mostly restricted to [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).  If you have a value `t` of type `T` and a value `k` of type `K extends keyof T`, then the compiler will generally accept that `t[k]` is of type `T[K]`.  That's my my suggestion here was to change your `G<T>` to a series of indexed accesses:

```
type G<T extends A> = T[number]['id'];

export const extractId = <T extends A>(array: T): G<T>[] => 
  array.map<G<T>>(({ id }) => id); // okay
```

---

If you can't do that or don't want to for your use case, the best thing to do is probably accept that the compiler is unable to really provide both type safety and usability inside your function implementation.  At that point, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress the errors after you triple check your code to make sure it conforms to the types you claim it does:

```
export const extractId = <T extends A>(array: T): G<T>[] =>
    array.map(z => z.id as G<T>);
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBJYATCAPC6CC8iUUSA3gFBJVIAuAnjMnkgLxlICW6AXEsAK5gARhABOSAL4BtALpIAPuy68oNUR2ABzSbPKVq9RkgDiAHgAqSbDQgYSeAHysk5qQOFiZUgORdvMgG49aissGAB7URokeHDgVVC1BBoUdGcLRNt0ewcAChBRURA6XnMASl4zcwdZVicCoroAOjAQGFMqhzzc0k40iTK6vrKgiT09QyZnXuU+QRFxaTlFGZ4kVXUtHRkJhmQqzLskR2dLayySVd4NADMxVH7agH4HpF5gCAA3MSDyG-5gPAaBw4kgbuFwhlzkdHLlZq53AsvAAiLjImQAGlopUGFBCABsINFNDRKhYHEEQiTnFwAkgAPT0qyFSIAQn0VA4NyQuUm4W5XFYLDYyMRYmRuKQ1LYAGZJAymWJRGzgtRYvFohBCWBnDQpAAGQIchkAKhicQSWogYF4VzmHlEdIkCiUaw2Gk0TqQJvpxr1AEY5GwrWA6YykBCYFAsQB3AAWIGiXJcnBIUlIszFogkWIzbrUHokO3IY3G2AiUXNGsSRSBqXSZywNhheQaxRxZOqtRYDmNbearRguQAXkNh01BSASJ0RuQgA)